# How to add items to an array outside promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, foreach, promise, async-await

this doubt is about promises. 
I need to add documents of the subcollection 'bar' into array intialized outside of the block

```
...
foo.bars = new Array<IBar>();
let manyBars = documentRef.collection('bar').listDocuments();
(await manyBars).forEach( barItem => {
    barItem.get().then(barDocument => {

        let bar: IBar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(barDocument.data()));
        if (foo.bars !== null) {
            foo.bars.push(bar);
            console.log('in');
        }
    });
});

console.log('out');
```

My console.log() prints firts 'out' and then 'in'. What am I doing wrong? 
forEach method has "await".

Comment: `get()` is also asynchronous and returns a promise. You won't be able to use await inside the forEach loop.  You will need another strategy.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Thank you, I tried with Promise.all(...) and it worked perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is, chiefly, expecting asynchronous `.then()` callbacks to complete in the line-order it would if it were synchronous. It is important to realise that `.then()` callbacks are executed after the current event thread has completed.

Whilst `await` is just a syntactical alternative for `.then()`, it largely allows asynchronous code to be written much as it would be if it was synchronous.

In general, it's good practice, within any given function, not to mix `.then()` and `await` syntax

Assuming `barDocument.data()` is synchronous, it should be as simple as this ...

```
...
try{
    let manyBars = await documentRef.collection('bar').listDocuments();
    let barDocuments = await Promise.all(manyBars.map(barItem => barItem.get()));
    let foo.bars = barDocuments.map(barDocument => barDocument.data());
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    // handle error as necessary.
    // return a value or re-throw the error.
}
```

If `barDocument.data()` is asynchronous, then you will need to introduce another `await Promise.all(...)`.